# What is this symbol next to some of the manuscript pages?

Tags: alan-wake

I started playing Alan Wake, and noticed that some manuscript pages have a strange symbol next to them:

[image: Manuscripts]

What does this symbol signify?

Comment: Check the lower left. :)

Comment: I simply cannot believe I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the page is only available on the Nightmare difficulty setting.